# Take screenshot of Visual blur view

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to take screenshot of visual blur view.

According to docs

> Many effects require support from the window that hosts the UIVisualEffectView. Attempting to take a snapshot of only the UIVisualEffectView will result in a snapshot that does not contain the effect. To take a snapshot of a view hierarchy that contains a UIVisualEffectView, you must take a snapshot of the entire UIWindow or UIScreen that contains it.

So I have following hierarchy

[image]

So I am taking full `UIView` screenshot and try to crop the rect of `viewScreenShot` but I am not able to do this

Here What I tried so far

```
 @IBAction func btnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0)

    //    self.viewScreenShot.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        self.view.drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(x: view.frame.origin.x, y: view.frame.origin.y, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height), afterScreenUpdates: true)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        let cgIImage =  image?.cgImage?.cropping(to: CGRect(origin: viewScreenShot.frame.origin, size: viewScreenShot.frame.size))

        let newImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgIImage!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImage.Orientation.up)

        (self.view.viewWithTag(90) as? UIImageView)?.image = newImage

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()


    }
```

Output

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figure it out.

Here is what I did

```
@IBAction func btnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0)

    //    self.viewScreenShot.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        self.view.drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(x: view.frame.origin.x, y: view.frame.origin.y, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height), afterScreenUpdates: true)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        // FULL


        let cgIImage =  image?.cgImage?.cropping(to: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: viewScreenShot.frame.origin.x * UIScreen.main.scale  , y: viewScreenShot.frame.origin.y * UIScreen.main.scale), size: CGSize(width: viewScreenShot.bounds.width * UIScreen.main.scale, height: viewScreenShot.bounds.height * UIScreen.main.scale)))

        let newImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgIImage!, scale: UIScreen.main.scale, orientation: UIImage.Orientation.up)

        (self.view.viewWithTag(90) as? UIImageView)?.image = newImage

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()


    }
```

There are two issues which are because of scale

So

I replaced

```
    let newImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgIImage!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImage.Orientation.up)
```

with

```
    let newImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgIImage!, scale: UIScreen.main.scale, orientation: UIImage.Orientation.up)
```

and

change this by multiply  `UIScreen.main.scale`

```
        let cgIImage =  image?.cgImage?.cropping(to: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: viewScreenShot.frame.origin.x * UIScreen.main.scale  , y: viewScreenShot.frame.origin.y * UIScreen.main.scale), size: CGSize(width: viewScreenShot.bounds.width * UIScreen.main.scale, height: viewScreenShot.bounds.height * UIScreen.main.scale)))
```

Output

[image]